# How to get the file from Amazon AWS S3 bucket from URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xamarin.forms

I've created an Amazon S3 bucket and I've uploaded the files/images from mobile phone app. I've to show the posts with a lot of images and the images are automatically bind for image URLs. But I don't know how to get the URL because images should not be public to show directly. How can I show them in my app?

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject',[
    'Bucket' => 'myinstaclassbucket',
'Key' => 'e12e682c-936d-4a97-a049-6f104dd7c904.jpg',
    ]);
$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd,$timetoexpire);
$presignedurl = (string) $request->getUri();
echo $presignedurl;
```

Comment: You need S3Client from here https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ to generate URL using secret key and access key. I could provide example, but it would be in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, It'll be great if you could give me an example in PHP because the service is developed in PHP. Thanks Justinas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use [AWS PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html). Also make sure you have valid Access key and Secret key.

Than everything is straight forward.

```
$bucket = 'some-bucket';
$key = 'mainFolder/subFolder/file.xx';

// Init client
$client = new S3Client([
    'key' => '*YOUR ACCESS KEY*',
    'secret' => '*YOUR SECRET KEY*',
]);

if ($client->doesObjectExists($bucket, $key)) {
    // If passing `expire` time you will get signed URL
    $url = $client->getObjectUrl($bucket, $key, time() + (60 * 60 * 2));
} else {
    $url = null;
}
```